# Why JavaScript Alert Message is not working ? Code Error cannot be indicated

Tags: javascript

Why JavaScript Alert Message is not working ?

```
var ckc = prompt ("Enter Your City");
ckc = ckc.toLowerCase();
var cities =["Aaan", "Baan", "Caan" ,"Daan"];

for (var i=0; i<=4 ; i++){
if (ckc === cities[i]){
alert ("Hum, Nice City");
}
}
```

Comment: hint: `toLowerCase()` might be part of your problem

Comment: define "not working". What should it do?

Comment: var cityToCheck = prompt("Enter your city"); cityToCheck = cityToCheck.toLowerCase(); var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"]; for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) { if (cityToCheck === cleanestCities[i]) { alert("It's one of the cleanest cities"); } }

@@ No, lower case problem ,It works --------

Comment: SOLVED : Should be :::
var cities =["aaan", "baan", "caan" ,"daan"]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if (ckc === cities[i].toLowerCase()){
```

since you have downcased `ckc` and `cities` array has upcase values, your original `if` condition would never work.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I think you meant to post this to the other answer

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, sorry

Comment: But this CODE WORKS (almost same)

var cityToCheck = prompt("Enter your city"); 
cityToCheck = cityToCheck.toLowerCase(); 
var cleanestCities = ["cheyenne", "santa fe", "tucson", "great falls", "honolulu"]; 
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) { 
if (cityToCheck === cleanestCities[i]) { 
alert("It's one of the cleanest cities"); 
   } 
 }

Comment: Because that array has all lower case values already.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code

```
ckc = ckc.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: While this does answer the question a bit of extra explanation would be good here.